# CKEditor : Change cursor position at the end of the Document

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor to edit documents and I want some additional functionalities too...

In my case, I want to set my cursor position at last of the document.

I'm Searching Everything in google.But I can't get the Solution.

How to I do this(set cursor position at the end of the document in CKEditor)?

[image]

I want to do the above thing what I'm mentioning in the Image File.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CKEDITOR carot position API will help me to do this things.So, I can able to position my cursor at any of the places I want in my editor.

I found the answer in the below URL

[Link for carot position set](https://ckeditor.com/old/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Get-caret-position)